# Service account confuse

Tags: sharepoint-server, service-account

Which accounts should added to the managed accounts in SharePoint and why?

Should add all service accounts and app pool account to the managed account or there is an exception?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should register the following service accounts to the Managed Accounts:

- SharePoint Farm Account.
- SharePoint Web Application Pool Account.
- SharePoint Service Application Pool Account.

Check also

- **[SharePoint 2019: Service Accounts Recommendations](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/sharepoint-2019-service-accounts-best-practice/)**
- **[SharePoint 2019: Register Managed Account using PowerShell](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/bulk-add-managed-account-powershell-sharepoint/)**

Answer (score -2):

Check official documentation [Account permissions and security settings in SharePoint Servers](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/install/account-permissions-and-security-settings-in-sharepoint-server-2016)